# __FILE__ returns different value when using binding.pry

Tags: ruby, pry, binding.pry

`__FILE__` returns the path of the current Ruby script file.

One potentially significant problem is that, if using `binding.pry`, `__FILE__` evaluates to `(pry)`. It is potentially problematic to have `__FILE__` evaluate to different values depending on whether it is evaluated in the context of `binding.pry`. For example,

```
$stdout.print "****************************************\n\n"
$stdout.print "FILE: #{__FILE__}\n\n"
$stdout.print "****************************************\n\n"

binding.pry
```

When the script pauses at `binding.pry`, I get:

```
__FILE__
# >> (pry)
```

Does anyone know any mechanism to get the path of the current file even in the context of `binding.pry`?

Comment: Assign it before stopping. `current_file = __FILE__; binding.pry`

Comment: FYI you don't need to use `pry` since Ruby 2.4: `binding.irb` is built-in and largely equivalent.

Comment: @Max The same issue presents itself in IRB as in pry.

Comment: @anothermh yep, my comment is totally unrelated to the question. Just pointing out that `pry` is no longer necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_file_` instead of `__FILE__`. For example, given two files:

```
# foo.rb
require 'pry'
require './bar'
binding.pry
b = Bar.new
```

and:

```
# bar.rb
require 'pry'
class Bar
  def initialize
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

Run them with `ruby foo.rb`:

```
ruby foo.rb

From: /Users/username/foo.rb @ line 3 :

    1:     require 'pry'
    2:     require './bar'
 => 3:     binding.pry
    4:     b = Bar.new

(main):1 ⇒ _file_
=> "/Users/username/foo.rb"
(main):2 ⇒ exit

From: /Users/username/bar.rb @ line 4 Bar#initialize:

    3: def initialize
 => 4:   binding.pry
    5: end

(#<Bar:0x00007fbb6caaff08>):1 ⇒ _file_
=> "/Users/username/bar.rb"
```

`_file_` and any other local variable names can be found in [`binding.local_variables`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Binding.html#method-i-local_variables).

Answer (score 1):

Sergio Tulentsev made a simple suggestion, assign `__FILE__` to a variable before invoking `binding.pry`.

anothermh, mentioned `_file_` which is available in binding pry.

In the end, I combined the two answers:

```
# When in the context of binding.pry, __FILE__ resolves to '(pry)',
# binding contains the local variable _file_ which always resolves to
# the current file, even when being evaluated in the context of binding.pry .
# _file_ is only available, in binding. This does the trick:

current_file = __FILE__.downcase == '(pry)' ? _file_ : __FILE__
```

Comment: Beware that `_file_` returns the absolute path while `__FILE__` does not, so do not expect them to be perfectly interchangeable if you're subsequently parsing the value of `current_file`. I don't see any reason not to continue using just `__FILE__`, since the only time I can see `_file_` being necessary is when manually typing into the REPL.